# Why do only some of my hooks get called?

Tags: 7, hooks

I made a test module and only a few of my hooks seem to get called. I get the Javascript console messages for the block_view, form_alter and form_user_login_alter hook functions when I do the corresponding actions. However, when I login, logout, view a node, create a node or delete a node I get nothing in the console. Shouldn't these hooks get called when I do those things? I reset my cache, disabled and enabled my module multiple times.
Here is the code for test_module.module:

```
<?php

function console_log ($stringIn) {
    print "<script>console.log('" . $stringIn . "');</script>";
}
function test_module_help ($path, $arg) {
    switch($path) {
        case "admin/help#test_module":
            return '<p>' . t("This is just a test module right now.") . '</p>';
            break;
    }
}
function test_module_insert ($node) {
    console_log("node inserted");
}
function test_module_user_login_submit (&$form, &$form_state) {
    console_log("login submitted");
}
function test_module_block_view ($delta = '') {
    console_log("block viewed");
}
function test_module_user_login (&$edit, $account) {
    console_log("user logged in");
}
function test_module_user_logout ($account) {
    console_log("user logged out");
}
function test_module_view ($node, $view_mode) {
    console_log("node viewed");
}
function test_module_form_alter (&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    console_log("form altered");
}
function test_module_delete ($node) {
    console_log("node deleted");
}
function test_module_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    console_log("user login form altered");
}
```

Here is the test_module.info file:

```
name = Test Module
description = just a test module
package = ZZ Test category
core = 7.x
```

Those two files are in sites/all/modules/test_module/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised doing a 'print' works at all and does not produce a headers already sent error.
Your hooks may well be being called.
Instead of calling your own console.log function, install the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and call dpm('my message');
It will give you a much better idea of what hook is and is not being called.

eg. (your module with devel enabled).

```
function test_module_help ($path, $arg) {
    switch($path) {
        case "admin/help#test_module":
            return '<p>' . t("This is just a test module right now.") . '</p>';
            break;
    }
}
function test_module_insert ($node) {
    dpm("node inserted");
}
function test_module_user_login_submit (&$form, &$form_state) {
    dpm("login submitted");
}
function test_module_block_view ($delta = '') {
    dpm("block viewed");
}
function test_module_user_login (&$edit, $account) {
    dpm("user logged in");
}
function test_module_user_logout ($account) {
    dpm("user logged out");
}
function test_module_view ($node, $view_mode) {
    dpm("node viewed");
}
function test_module_form_alter (&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm("form altered");
}
function test_module_delete ($node) {
    dpm("node deleted");
}
function test_module_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm("user login form altered");
}
```

Comment: Much better. I'm still a little confused after testing each function. After logging in, logging out, creating a node, deleting a node and loading a node with a block in it, here are my results:

Comment: There is a permission the see the dpm messages. By default is is only user 1 I think. So if you are not logged in you will not see the messages unless you change the permission to let anonymous users see the messages.

Comment: The ones that still don't show: hook_login_submit, hook_login_alter, hook_logout, hook_insert, hook_view, hook_delete.
So the logout, login submit and login alter ones don't show because of permissions. That makes sense. But I don't understand why hook_insert, hook_view and hook_delete don't show anything. I read the docs for those but I don't understand how they are different from the hook_node_ ones.

Comment: As far as I can see, your hooks should be being called. Try calling `watchdog` instead of dpm. eg `watchdog('my module', 'insert');`. Thn check your watchdog logs.

Comment: I think I understand everything that's going on now. The only login or logout hook that makes a dpm message show up is user_login because my admin account is logged out or not finished logging in when I call dpm in the other hooks. Also, I found a better explanation about hook_view and hook_insert than I saw in the docs. Apparently, and please let me know if I haven't quite got this right yet, hook_view and hook_insert will only work on nodes whose type is defined in the module in which I am declaring the hooks. I will try out watchdog, too. Thanks for all of your help, I was really struggling

Comment: Those hooks are hook_node_insert, hook_node_update, etc. not hook_insert.

Comment: I put hook_node_insert and hook_node_view in my test module and they were called when I created and viewed a basic page. hook_insert and hook_view were not called. I just wanted to be clear on the reason that hook_insert and and hook_view were not called. It's because the type of node that I was creating and inserting (basic page) was not created by my test module, right? If I create a node type in my module and then test it by making and viewing a node of that type, will that module's hook_view and hook_insert be called?

Comment: Ahh yes, that is correct.